# Parse existing YAML file to create new template (remove value from key-value pair)

Tags: ruby, yaml

I'm looking to take an existing YAML file, configured like this:

```
en: 
  calendars: 
    gregorian: 
      days: 
        format: 
          abbreviated: 
            fri: Fri
            mon: Mon
            sat: Sat
            sun: Sun
            thu: Thu
            tue: Tue
            wed: Wed
          narrow: :"calendars.gregorian.days.stand-alone.narrow"
          wide: 
            fri: Friday
            mon: Monday
            sat: Saturday
            sun: Sunday
            thu: Thursday
            tue: Tuesday
            wed: Wednesday
(etc.)
```

And remove the values from the key-value pair. Basically it would look like:

```
en: 
  calendars: 
    gregorian: 
      days: 
        format: 
          abbreviated: 
            fri:
            mon:
            sat:
            sun:
            thu:
            tue:
            wed:
```

I used Psych in 1.9.3 to import the YAML file as a hash (`Psych.load_file` etc.) - is there a function I can call via Psych or maybe just plain Ruby to remove all the values from these pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the yaml has been loaded in a hash, just use ruby to transform the data structure.

```
format = loaded_yaml['en']['calendars']['gregorian']['days']['format']
format['abbreviated'] = format['abbreviated'].keys.inject({}) {|m,k| m[k] = nil; m }
```